# Using class id from array for query

Tags: database, query, array, id

I'm using Event Calendar 3. Since there seems to be no easy way of querying all upcoming events as posts, I tried it this way, getting the IDs from the DB and querying the posts from that:

```
<?php if(!ec3_check_installed(__('Upcoming Events','ec3')))
    return;
global $ec3,$wpdb,$wp_version;

$calendar_entries = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT
        p.id AS id
    FROM $ec3->schedule s
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->posts p ON s.post_id=p.id
    WHERE p.post_status='publish'
    AND end>='$ec3->today' $and_before
    ORDER BY start $limit_numposts", OBJECT_K
); 

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post__in' => $calendar_entries,
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

It doesnt work, obviously because the array looks like this, if I var_dump it:

```
array(2) {
    [37]=> object(stdClass)#2183 (1) { 
        ["id"]=> string(2) "37"
    }
    [8]=> object(stdClass)#2186 (1) { 
        ["id"]=> string(1) "8" 
    } 
}
```

How can I use this array for my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this after your `$wpdb` query:

```
// collect calendar id's
$ids = array();
foreach( $calendar_entries as  $calendar_entries):
        array_push( $ids, $calendar_entries->id );
endforeach;

// query the above calendar id's
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post__in' => $ids,
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

You can also modify the `WP_Query` by using [posts_where](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where), [posts_join](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_join)
and [posts_clauses](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_clauses).